# Only one primary partition can be "active", What about logical drive?

Tags: partition

As far as I understand "active" means that a partition is bootable, therefore an operating system can be installed on it.

I just installed an Operating System on one of my logical partition and it's booting fine. Does it mean that its "active" now?

Comment: What "Operating System"?

Comment: Operating System: Windows 7

Comment: I made partitions with the help of Partitioning Tool in the SuSE DVD and then installed Windows 7 to a logical drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active partition is used by the default Windows boot loader to determine which partition to load an operating system from. However using LILO or GRUB as your boot loader can instead allow any partition to be booted from (as you get a menu of operating systems presented), and consequently the active partition marker is not needed.